# Get CURL RAW Post JSON Data in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am getting raw data sent from server through cURL where data type is JSON, like

```
curl -X POST https://website-to-post-data.com/listener.php -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"user_id": "1234", "Date": "2017-04-06", "first_name": "First Name", "last_name": "Last Name", "email": "someemail@email.com"}'
```

Now I want to read this data posted to my listener.php file and decode the JSON data to PHP array and finally insert it in our MySQL database.

Here is the code of https://website-to-post-data.com/listener.php file

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
$ch = curl_init( 'https://website-to-post-data.com/listener.php' );
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  'Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8',
  'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8',
  'Expect: 100-continue',
  'Connection: Keep-Alive') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
echo $result;
$jsArray = json_decode($result);
?>
```

Why I am getting blank output on executing the above code and not receiving the data?

Comment: Try to add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` , and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` on your `$options`

Comment: @RyanAW Sorry but your suggestion did not make any difference

Comment: If this is your entire script `$json_string` is never being set. Might want to comment that line out for the time being. You'll also want to `var_dump` the `$result` variable rather than echoing it. In the event of a Curl error `$result` is gonna be set to `false` which won't be apparent if you're echoing the variable.

Comment: @MikeMollick sorry I have updated the $json_string